# Android Notifications while screen is off

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to invoke notifications while screen is off.
That is works with Huawei p10 Lite (Serial: `HUAWEIWAS-LX1A` Android 8.0.0), however it does not work with Android 10 Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 (`QP1A.190711.020`). Nevertheless, notifications can pass through the lock-screen.

Here is my code:

```
    fun Notifications () {
        mNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.icon))
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setColor(NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT)
            .setColorized(true)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "my-app", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
                description = "Test"
            }
            channel.importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            channel.shouldVibrate()
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.vibrationPattern=longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000)
            channel.canBypassDnd()
            channel.lightColor = NotificationCompat.COLOR_DEFAULT
            channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
```

Members of MainActivity class:

```
    val soundUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    lateinit var mNotification : NotificationCompat.Builder
    lateinit var mNotificationManager : NotificationManager
    val mNotificationID: Int = 1
    val CHANNEL_ID : String  = "com.example.myapp"
```

Here is how i am using it:

```
with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
    notify(mNotificationID, mNotification.build())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. so I make wake device code on onMessageReceived()

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Dlog.d("From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Dlog.d("Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Dlog.d("Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        //wakeup devices when sleep.
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE );
        @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag")
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock( PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG" );
        wakeLock.acquire(3000);

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
    }
```

and set notification in sendNotification() as I want. and it works.